# post request using axios on Laravel 5.5

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios, laravel-5.5

i'm trying to make some requests using axios and the last Laravel version 5.5
after configure the X-CSRF fields and all
my code is simple :

```
        axios.post('/post-contact',{name:'Kamal Abounaim'})
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error.response.data)
        })
```

but i get this error : 419 (unknown status)
what the problem supposed to be
Thanks for answering

Comment: Is this happening after you've been on the page for a while or straight after a page load? Are you getting any other errors in your console?

Comment: sorry didn't say this comment,
no i have no errors if i tried with axios.get it works but with post no 
i create a plain form and try to post and it works to

Comment: If you check the network tab in your browser is it definitely including either the `X-XSRF` OR `X-CSRF` header in the request or the `_token` in the body?]

Comment: i checked it still not working

Comment: It would be polite to select a right answer.  @KamalL'azz

Answer (score 14):

This is happening because of the csrf-token. Just add meta tag with the csrf-token in the `<head>` and add that token to axios header like so.

```
// in the <head>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<script type="text/javascript">
    // For adding the token to axios header (add this only one time).
    var token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;

    // send contact form data.
    axios.post('/post-contact',{name:'Kamal Abounaim'
    }).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error.response.data)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[A 419 error seems to be Authentification Timeout](http://getstatuscode.com/419). Your code looks fine to me, so it seems the error is with the `post-contact` endpoint? Try testing that endpoint alone, in a tool like [postman.](https://www.getpostman.com/)

Comment: Thanks bro but with the previous version it was okey
is the 5.5 needs new tools or i'm not understanding

Comment: Hmm strange, not sure. Hopefully someone else might be able to chip in here. I use Laravel but not upgraded to 5.5 yet.

Comment: yeah if you say it, i hate those situations :(

Comment: Laravel will throw this error only if you forgot about the CSRF token.